# How to align part of the text on a button?

Tags: java, android, button

I want to align my text on a button in the following way:

```
 
Thickness         20mm
```

I want thickness to be aligned to the left and the value(20mm) to be aligned to the right of the button. I initially went with something like

```
thickness_button.setText(res.getString(R.string.THICKNESS)
                              +"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"+value);
```

This worked initially but when I change the locale the `THICKNESS` string changes accordingly and is very long so the value gets pushed to the next line and looks like this:

```
 
Thickness         
20mm
```

How can I resolve this problem? Is there a solution that does not involve changing the UI element (button)?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible withoud replacing the button. I would create a LinearLayout like so:
<LinearLayout params
background="thebuttonbackground">
<TextView params  
layout_width="wrap_content"
text="Thickness"/>
<View
layout_width="wrap_content"
layout_weight="1"/>
<TextView
layout_width="wrap_content"
text="20mm"/>
</LinearLayout>
(fill in aditional parameters)
(I'm not posting this as an answer, as you want a solution that's not replacing the button, but if you want to, I can create a more detailed answer..)

Answer (score 1):

A Button is not a lot different from a TextView/View. I suggest not using a Button and using a FrameLayout with 2 TextViews with layout gravity being LEFT and RIGHT.

Just add a click listener on your FrameLayout and you've built a button.

```
    frameLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //...
        }
    });



<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp">   
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytext"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:text="XXX"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myvalue"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:text="YYY"
        />
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

even if you explicitly mentioned "without changing UI element" answer is use a layout with two textview (one left aligned and other right aligned) and give this layout  look and feel of button .

i can't find any valid reason which can restrict you from going this way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this using Button. *You have to create your own view with a layout and two TextView. and use that view instead of Button.*